# What is the best way to convert base64 encoded text column to a bytea column in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, type-conversion, base64

I have a database with ~100K rows. One of the rows is base64 encoded binary data. I've learned that it would be more efficient to store the data as bytea and perform encoding dynamically.

Question: What is the best way to make this conversion in my database? My leading idea is to add a new column with an alter table statement, write a python script that iterates over every row (performs the conversion and re-inserts into the database) and then remove the other column with another alter table statement.

Are there any better (more efficient) ways of doing this? If it matters, the base64 is url-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`decode(string, 'base64')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-CONVERSIONS)